# Kafka Producer AWSSchemaRegistryConstants properties for YAML File

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I have set up a Kakfa producer using my own ProducerFactory bean, it uses AWS Glue Schema Registry to register AVRO schemas, I want to move all the properties to a YML file but I dont know how to declare AWSSchemaRegistryConstants properties in a yml file, any ideas? The code looks as follow:

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
class KafkaProducerConfig {

 @Bean
 fun producerConfigs(): Map<String, Any> {
    val props: MutableMap<String, Any> = HashMap()
    props[ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG] = "localhost:9092"
    props[ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG] = IntegerSerializer::class.java
    props[ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG] = AWSKafkaAvroSerializer::class.java
    props[AWSSchemaRegistryConstants.AWS_REGION] = "ap-southeast-2"
    props[AWSSchemaRegistryConstants.SCHEMA_AUTO_REGISTRATION_SETTING] = "true"
    props[AWSSchemaRegistryConstants.SCHEMA_NAME] = "ac-schema"
    props[AWSSchemaRegistryConstants.REGISTRY_NAME] = "poc-registry"
    return props
}

@Bean
 fun producerFactory(): ProducerFactory<Int, AcCk> {
    return DefaultKafkaProducerFactory(producerConfigs())
}

@Bean
 fun kafkaTemplate(): KafkaTemplate<Int, AcCk> {
    return KafkaTemplate(producerFactory())
 }

}
```

YML File:

```
spring:
 kafka:
  producer:
   bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
   key:
     serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerSerializer
   value:
     serializer: com.amazonaws.services.schemaregistry.serializers.avro.AWSKafkaAvroSerializer

   AWSSchemaRegistryConstants ??????
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The indentation under producer is correct, however, you need to open the enum/class for `AWSSchemaRegistryConstants` and see what each of the properties are and copy the strings over into the config. What you're basically asking for is no different than trying to use `ProducerConfig` object in the YAML, for example

Or you can continue to build KafkaTemplate in code rather than use YAML since that'll allow you to have compile time property validation and use the enum class

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer. Is there any other benefit of keeping that configuration in the code instead of the YML file. It seems to be, i am not sure about it completely that it is the best practice to move out all those configurations from the code base and put them in a YML file?

Comment: IMO, main reason to use the config file properties is for allowing profile overrides, but that could just as easily be done in code with environmental variables

Comment: @D.B did this actually work for you? It's not working for me. It doesn't add any of the properties under `AWSSchemaRegistryConstants`

Comment: @user32 You can't actually put `AWSSchemaRegistryConstants.*` literals in the config. They need to be the actual runtime strings

Comment: @OneCricketeer right, the enum values so for example `AWS_REGION` will be `region`. That's what I did. I opened the enum class and used the string values in the config but it doesn't pick them up.

Comment: AFAIK, it needs to be under `spring.kafka.producer.properties.region`, for example